# Jenkins Pipeline - How to get build number when restarting?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins pipeline ( Blue Ocean Style ) and i am trying apply Restarting option.

When Restart Build ( parent ), It will create a new build ( child ) from the first one ( parent ).

How from the second build ( child ) can i get the build number ( parent ) ?

Answer (score 0):

When you open the new job, don't you see Rebuilds build#

Comment: I am talking about : How to get the parent Build number using code, environment variable